# No axis named Stats for object type DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, pandas-apply

I am trying to reuse the defined function for multiple rows in a DataFrame. But I am getting an error:

> No axis named Stats for object type DataFrame

```
d = {'Person': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],'Stats':[17, 117, -52, 100, -6, 101]}
ages = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def my_jr(amount):
if amount > 0:
    print('amount greater than zero')
elif amount < 0:
    print('amount lesser than zero')
else:
    pass
ages.apply(my_jr,'Stats')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the argument you're passing to Panda's `apply` method is not as expected.

The second argument (its actually a keyword argument) is the `axis` -- either 0 or 1. From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is
> either the DataFrame's index (axis=0) or the DataFrame's columns
> (axis=1).

So, in this case, you should be passing 1 as the axis. Each argument to your function `my_jr` would be a Pandas [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object, which you can then index at `Stats` to get the numerical value to compare.

Here is a corrected version:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'Person': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'Stats': [17, 117, -52, 100, -6, 101]
}

ages = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def my_jr(series):
    amount = series['Stats']
    if amount > 0:
        print('amount greater than zero')
    elif amount < 0:
        print('amount lesser than zero')
    else:
        pass

ages.apply(my_jr, 1)
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
amount greater than zero
amount greater than zero
amount lesser than zero
amount greater than zero
amount lesser than zero
amount greater than zero
```

This isn't a surprising misconception with how Panda's `apply` works. I suggest reading more [examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) of it in action to understand how to use it correctly.